# Why I get space in the top of the view in _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I use asp.net MVC 5 in my project.

Here the generated code in _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container topNavBtn">
            <div class="navbar-header ">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I remove code from this div:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

to create my own header:

```
<body>
    <header style="background-color:green">My Header</header>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

But in view I get space in top of the page:

[image]

Any ide why I get space above?

Comment: that header element has content ("My Header"), so it gets height

Comment: can you inspect your header in devloper tools and attach screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Using a fixed navbar in Bootstrap requires setting padding-top on the body to provide sufficient space for the navbar. That space at the top is where your navbar is supposed to go, but you haven't included it. If you don't want the navbar, simply remove the padding-top from the body element. Otherwise, add the navbar to fill the space.